# Flutter- pass MaterialPageRoute as parameter in another widget

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

I want to pass MaterialPageRoute as a parameter into another page. Like if want to pass *onPressed((){})* to other page we declared it as

```
FirstPage({
    this.onPressed,
  });
final GestureTapCallback onPressed;
```

How could I pass `MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SecondPage())` to other page as a parameter?

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do that:

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {

  const MyApp({Key? key}): super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: FirstPage(
        materialPageRoute: MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const SecondPage()),
      )
    );
  }
}

class FirstPage extends StatelessWidget {

  const FirstPage({
    Key? key,
    required this.materialPageRoute,
  }): super(key: key);

  final MaterialPageRoute materialPageRoute;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: TextButton(
          onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).push(materialPageRoute),
          child: const Text('Navigate to SecondPage'),
        ),
      )
    );
  }
}

class SecondPage extends StatelessWidget {

  const SecondPage({Key? key}): super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: const Center(
        child: Text('Second Page'),
      ),
    );
  }

}
```